# How to create a dictionary from two lists?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have two different lists, and I need them to be displayed like this. I feel like I'm close but the program doesn't work. Also, a version with `zip` wouldn't work for me here.

```
>>> list_to_dict(["a", "b"], ["13", "7" ])
{ "a": "13", "b": "7" }
```

That's what I have now:

```
def lists_to_dict():
    x = ['a', 'b']
    y = ['13', '7']
    d = {}
    for i in range(len(x)):
        d[x[i]] = y[i]
    return d

lists_to_dict()
```

Comment: Why doesn't zip work?

Comment: This code works. If you make `x` and `y` parameters instead of hard-coding them, and then pass them in like you do above, it will also work. What's wrong with it?

Comment: hard-coding parameters helped with the issue I was having. Thank you

Answer (score 5):

`dict(zip(x,y))` should be all you need.

Comment: I think you mean `dict(zip(x,y))`.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> a = ["a", "b"]
>>> b = ["13", "7" ]
>>> print dict(zip(a,b)) 
{'a': '13', 'b': '7'}
>>>
```

Comment: Please add some explanation!

Answer (score 0):

Same zip-less solution that's being tossed about repackaged as a comprehension:

```
def lists_to_dict(k, v):
    return { k[i]: v[i] for i in range(min(len(k), len(v))) }

>>> lists_to_dict(['a', 'b'], [13, 7])
{'a': 13, 'b': 7}
```